# How can I make legends colourful? And how can I put value in bars?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

```
\documentclass[border=5mm] {standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{xcolor, color}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \definecolor{SpecialYellow}{HTML}{F9DC21}
    \definecolor{SpecialGreen}{HTML}{46A62E}
    \definecolor{SpecialBlue}{HTML}{4192F5}

    \pgfplotstableread{
    Label   Engine  Check   OS
    Cached  4.49    0.83    4
    Normal  12.45   3.9     12
    }\datatable

    \begin{axis}[xbar stacked, xmin=0, xmax=30, ytick=data, yticklabels from table={\datatable}{Label}, draw=black, height=25mm, width=5cm, legend style={at={(0,1.5)}, anchor=west,legend columns=3, area legend} ]
        \addlegendentry{Engine}
        \addplot [fill=SpecialBlue, draw=none] table[x=Engine] {\datatable};
        \addlegendentry{Check}
        \addplot [fill=SpecialGreen, draw=white] table[x=Check] {\datatable};
        \addlegendentry{OS}
        \addplot [fill=SpecialYellow, draw=white] table[x=OS] {\datatable};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172814/tikz-stacked-bar-chart-with-text/172847?s=12|0.1782#172847

Comment: What do you mean with "colourful legend"?

Answer (score 1):

[area legend] needs to be outside the [legend style].

I couldn't figure out what the y coordinates were for this plot.  0 corresponds to below the bottom.  The center of the lower bar is at about 5 and the upper bar at about 12.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm] {standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{xcolor, color}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
  Label   Engine  Check   OS
  Cached  4.49    0.83    4
  Normal  12.45   3.9     12
}\datatable

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \definecolor{SpecialYellow}{HTML}{F9DC21}
    \definecolor{SpecialGreen}{HTML}{46A62E}
    \definecolor{SpecialBlue}{HTML}{4192F5}

    \begin{axis}[xbar stacked, xmin=0, xmax=30, ytick=data, yticklabels from table={\datatable}{Label}, 
      draw=black, height=25mm, width=5cm, tick align=outside,
      legend style={at={(0,1.5)}, anchor=west,legend columns=3}, area legend]
        \addlegendentry{Engine}
        \addplot [fill=SpecialBlue, draw=none] table[x=Engine] {\datatable};
        \addlegendentry{Check}
        \addplot [fill=SpecialGreen, draw=white] table[x=Check] {\datatable};
        \addlegendentry{OS}
        \addplot [fill=SpecialYellow, draw=white] table[x=OS] {\datatable};
        \coordinate (A) at (axis cs: 4.49,5);
    \end{axis}
    \node[inner sep=0pt,left] at (A) {\scriptsize 4.49};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: bar plot]