# Segmented bar chart under tikz plot

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart, nodes-near-coords

I'm trying to create a segmented bar chart (stacked bar chart) under my `tikz` plot:

[image]

For each point, I want to make a segmented bar chart directly below the point.  The segmented bar chart for each point should look something like:

[image]

Where each segmentation of each respective bar should sum to 1. Sometimes there will be up to 10 segments under one bar and each of these relative frequencies must sum to 1.  Each segmentation should display a number within it (preferably centered in the middle) between 0 and 1 to visually show how "big" it is directly on the plot.

The only relevant link I found explaining stacked bar charts was:
[Tikz Stacked Bar Chart with Text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172814/tikz-stacked-bar-chart-with-text)

Here is the code to `pgfplots` plot that I've created thus far:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
    title={My Title},
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={->},
    ylabel near ticks,
    xlabel near ticks,
    ymin=0, ymax=0.05,
    scaled y ticks = false,
    yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
    xlabel={x-axis},
    ylabel={y-axis}]

\addplot [only marks, mark=o] table{
11  0.0215
12  0.0216
13  0.0207
14  0.0202
15  0.0197
16  0.0195
17  0.0196
18  0.0192
19  0.0188
20  0.0183
21  0.0178
22  0.0175
23  0.0176
24  0.017
25  0.0169
};

\addplot [style=very thick, color=red] table{
10.58   0.0222
10.923  0.022
11.421  0.0218
13.459  0.0208
14.736  0.0203
16  0.0198
16.525  0.0196
16.878  0.0195
17.9    0.0191
18.503  0.0189
19.835  0.0184
22.27   0.0177
22.641  0.0176
22.728  0.0175
24.681  0.017
24.822  0.0169
};

\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Since I might have however many points on the x-axis, I am trying to make the widths of the stacked bars be able to scale appropriately so that they don't run into each other.  Usually I'm handling between 15 and 25 points, but sometimes over 70 or even 80.  At this point, I understand that the segmented bars will become cluttered, which is why I work only with 15 to 25 points at a time.

Is there a utility or something that I can use within `tikz` to directly make a segmented bar chart under my graph?

**UPDATE:**

I recently found this documentation, which shows almost exactly what I am looking to achieve with the stacked bar chart: http://pgfplots.net/tikz/examples/stacked-bar-plot/

I am of the opinion that the easiest way to draw these bars would be to use the open circle as the top middle anchor point.  However, I am still unsure about the scaling business if there are many points to consider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not 100% sure if I have understood your question right, but hopefully it
is not so far away from what you really wanted to do.

I think the simplest solution is to draw two `axis` environments on top of each
other; one holding the stacked bar plots and the other the mark and line plot.

For more details on how the solution works, please have a look at the comments
in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
    % create a dummy table file that contains the data table provided in your MWE
    % which I extended by some random points representing the percentages of
    % the bar values. The bar values in this case sum up to 1 in each row
    \begin{filecontents*}{dummy.txt}
        x   sum     y1         y2         y3
        11  0.0215  2.772E-01  2.458E-01  4.770E-01
        12  0.0216  8.413E-01  1.104E-03  1.576E-01
        13  0.0207  1.826E-01  6.898E-01  1.276E-01
        14  0.0202  9.010E-01  7.453E-02  2.443E-02
        15  0.0197  9.127E-01  5.292E-02  3.434E-02
        16  0.0195  8.263E-01  1.474E-01  2.625E-02
        17  0.0196  6.792E-01  2.355E-01  8.525E-02
        18  0.0192  6.071E-01  3.538E-01  3.901E-02
        19  0.0188  7.459E-02  3.337E-01  5.917E-01
        20  0.0183  9.621E-01  1.010E-02  2.780E-02
        21  0.0178  2.623E-01  3.666E-01  3.712E-01
        22  0.0175  5.252E-01  2.602E-01  2.146E-01
        23  0.0176  2.948E-01  5.312E-01  1.740E-01
        24  0.0170  1.991E-01  6.592E-01  1.416E-01
        25  0.0169  7.063E-01  2.581E-01  3.559E-02
    \end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        % use this `compat' level or higher to make use of the advanced featuers
        % regarding `nodes near coords'
        compat=1.9,
        % create a style with the options that are in common for both axis
        % environments
        my axis style/.style={
            axis lines=middle,
            % added `xmin' and `xmax' values
            xmin=11,
            xmax=25,
            ymin=0,
            ymax=0.025,
            % enlarge the x limit by an absolute value so it is independend
            % of axis scaling `width'
            enlarge x limits={abs=0.5},
            scaled y ticks=false,
            yticklabel style={
                /pgf/number format/.cd,
                    fixed,
                    precision=3,
                    zerofill,
            },
            % to have both axis environments the same size, scale only the
            % axis, because the second one doesn't need any axis lines and
            % with that of course tick labels and axis labels
            scale only axis=true,
        },
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % first (lower) axis to draw the stacked bars
    \begin{axis}[
        % apply the created style
        my axis style,
        % but we don't need any axis here
        hide axis,
        % we want to stack the ybars
        ybar stacked,
        % and they should `nodes near coords'
        nodes near coords={
            % which should print numbers in percent as fixed values without
            % any decimal numbers
            \pgfmathprintnumber[
                fixed,
                precision=0,
            ]{\myvalue}\%
        },
        % so the `nodes near coords' fit the bars and don't overlap, provide
        % some additional style options
        nodes near coords style={
            font=\tiny,
            rotate=90,
        },
        % for all `\addplot table' commands use this column for the x values
        table/x=x,
    ]
        % cycle through the stacked bar `\addplot's
        \foreach \i in {2,...,4} {
            \addplot table [
                % calculate the real height of the individual stacked bars
                % (for simplicity we use the index numbers of the respective
                %  columns in the data file)
                y expr=\thisrow{sum}*\thisrowno{\i},
                % and store the value which should be shown as `node near coords'
                % value in the variable `\myvalue'
                visualization depends on={\thisrowno{\i}*100 \as \myvalue},
            ] {dummy.txt};
        }
    \end{axis}
    % now we plot on top of the other axis environment the mark and line plot
    \begin{axis}[
        % again we apply created style
        my axis style,
        % and now the other "normal" axis options
        title={My Title},
        axis line style={->},
        ylabel near ticks,
        xlabel near ticks,
        xlabel={x-axis},
        ylabel={y-axis},
    ]
        \addplot [only marks, mark=o] table [x=x,y=sum] {dummy.txt};
        \addplot [style=very thick, color=red] table {
            10.58   0.0222
            10.923  0.022
            11.421  0.0218
            13.459  0.0208
            14.736  0.0203
            16      0.0198
            16.525  0.0196
            16.878  0.0195
            17.9    0.0191
            18.503  0.0189
            19.835  0.0184
            22.27   0.0177
            22.641  0.0176
            22.728  0.0175
            24.681  0.017
            24.822  0.0169
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]