# Adding nodes near coordinates to bar plot but from different series

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to annotate a bar plot with some markers or numbers to indicate the significance of some results. The significance is given in a different column from the main value.

Just to give an example of more or less what I would like to do:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableread{
    1    10 0.84     50 0.75      10    0.22     30 0.24 
    2    40 0.38     60 0.96     15 0.42     90 0.28
    3    20 0.42     60 0.42     15 0.24     60 0.86
}\mytable

\begin{document}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar,enlarge x limits=0.2,bar width=7pt,xtick={1,2,3,4}
    ]
    \addplot table [x index=0,y index=1] {\mytable};
    \addplot table [x index=0,y index=3] {\mytable};
    \addplot table [x index=0,y index=5] {\mytable};
    \addplot table [x index=0,y index=7] {\mytable};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
% I would like to mark bars where adjacent value is greater than 0.95
% more specifically: column 2 for value 2

% I would also like to add a different mark where adjacent value is greater than 0.85 (but less than 0.95)
% more specifically: column 4 for value 3
\end{document}
```

[image]

The exact marks are not important; this is just to give the idea.

I know `nodes near coords` may help here, but I don't know how to get this from a different series.

(Also with the formatting of my plot (the above is just an example) I don't believe I will have room to give the actual values, rather I'll probably want to convert the values to some sort of mark on the bar. I understand this is a different question though so I'm interested in focusing on the first problem.)

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172814/tikz-stacked-bar-chart-with-text/172847?s=1|1.0621#172847

Comment: Thanks John. That's useful but in my case I have over 400 bars and will have to manually mark over 120. I'm thus hoping for a more automated solution. :)

Comment: I just found this question, which seems relevant: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80012/different-color-for-individual-bar-in-bar-chart-adding-bar-labels (just trying to adapt it to my problem)

Comment: If you want to automate the process, use a foreach loop and \pgfplotstablegetelem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a suggestion using `point meta=explicit symbolic`, `nodes near coords` and `every node near coord/.append style`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pgfplotstableread{
    1    10 0.84     50 0.75      10    0.22     30 0.24 
    2    40 0.38     60 0.96     15 0.42     90 0.28
    3    20 0.42     60 0.42     15 0.24     60 0.86
}\mytable

\begin{document}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar,enlarge x limits=0.2,bar width=7pt,xtick={1,2,3,4},
        point meta=explicit symbolic,
        nodes near coords={
          \ifdim \pgfplotspointmeta pt > 0.95pt 
            \textcolor{green}{\huge$\bullet$}%
          \else 
            \ifdim \pgfplotspointmeta pt > 0.85pt
              \textcolor{green!50!blue!50}{\huge$\bullet$}%
          \fi\fi
        },
        every node near coord/.append style={inner sep=0pt,anchor=center}
    ]
    \addplot table [x index=0,y index=1,meta index=2] {\mytable};
    \addplot table [x index=0,y index=3,meta index=4] {\mytable};
    \addplot table [x index=0,y index=5,meta index=6] {\mytable};
    \addplot table [x index=0,y index=7,meta index=8] {\mytable};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

or with

```
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,enlarge x limits=0.2,bar width=7pt,xtick={1,2,3,4},
    point meta=explicit symbolic,
    nodes near coords={
      \ifdim \pgfplotspointmeta pt > 0.95pt
        \textcolor{green}{\huge$\star$}%
      \else 
        \ifdim \pgfplotspointmeta pt > 0.85pt
          \textcolor{green!50!blue!50}{\huge$\star$}%
      \fi\fi
    }
]
```

[image]

Comment: I spent ages at this and eventually gave up. This is awesome help, thanks a million!